# Rails + Facebook - how to autopost to Facebook page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-access-token, fb-graph

I've created a Facebook Page and I have a Rails app.
My goal is to post automatic statuses to this page as the page owner, but I have problem with **access_token** - how to obtain the access token and use it?

I saw the gem called **fb_graph**, which could be appropriate for this task. But my worries are, how to obtain all tokens and needed credentials for posting statuses from the Rails app automatically every day?

Thanks

Comment: Did you create a facebook application already? You could create a fb application and connect with this gem: https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook to your application, through fb will provide the correct credentials for you. if you are using devise currently, check out this article for omniauth authentication: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Comment: Yes, I made some steps to be closer to the goal. At the moment, I am solving the issue regarding to the **Access Token**. I generated one here - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=1194396249%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2C%20manage_pages - the problem is, that this token will expire in 2 hours or so. Is there any way to get something like a **pernament access token**?

Comment: I think fb access_tokens always will expire. Normally you will renew the token, if you login with facebook. But you do not want to login within the browser, you want to have a permanent connection from your backend to facebook for automatic posts? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct Mattherick.